# How to subtract negative decimals in Sql Server using Insert Into

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a query that tracks the history of decimal values in 2 tables.

Table1

```
PK  Num1   D1        D2
1   1      -0.00375  -0.005
2   1      -0.00325
```

Table2

```
PK   Num1   D1        D2
1    1      -0.00375  -0.0025
2    2      -0.005
```

Table3 (The History Table)

```
Num1  OldD2     NewD2     D2Difference
1     -0.005  -0.0025  0.0000//This is where I am having trouble
```

My query will add the 2 D2 values but not subtract.  It always returns 0.00
Here is my query.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO Table3
SELECT Table1.Num1, Table1.D2, Table2.D2, (Table1.D2 - Table2.D2)
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Num1 = Table2.Num1 AND Table1.D1 = Table2.D1
COMMIT
```

Again, I can add to the 2 decimals but subtracting always returns 0.00.  I know I'm missing the trees through the forest (or is it the other way around?).

**NOTE:** All decimals are (5,5) and the joins are a result of tables 1 and 2 having a unique D1 value for each Num1.

Comment: I tested your query with the exact same values, and `(Table1.D2 - Table2.D2)` is giving me -0.002500 as a result

Comment: See my last comment below on @sll answer.  Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are selecting only D1 which are equal in both tables - substract operation will return 0.00

Just remove JOIN condition `AND Table1.D1 = Table2.D1`

**EDIT:** Note

As question was changed my answer is not obvious because initial sql query was changed

Comment: The problem with that is that my 2 tables would not be joined together properly. Each Num1 col has a unique D1. Tabl1 D1 = -.00375 and Table2 D1 = -0.00350

Comment: But your INNER JOIN condition select only equal T1.D1 and T2.D1, so T1.D1 - T2 - D1 == 0.00

Comment: Ok, duh I see what your saying.  However, if I use the same query but subtract values from say D2 col, the same things happens.

Comment: Ok provide please `SELECT TOP 10 * ` rows from both T1 and T2 and update your question

Comment: Your update completely changes the things, but does not make sense to me unfortunately.... because SELECT `(-0.005 - (-0.0025))` returns -0.0025 anyway

Comment: You are correct.  That is what it should return but instead it returns .00.  I tried subtracted a few different values and they worked as expected. Could this be a rounding issue?  It shouldn't since all decimal columns are (5,5). Thanks for being patient

Comment: Thanks to @sll for providing good comments.  I marked his as answer because he made me rethink everything.  My issue was that the D2 column on Table3 WAS NOT a (5,5) decimal column as I had stated.  It was a (5,2) and was thus truncating my results to 0.0.  My bad, nothing to see here.